# Terminal: How to move files to the last used directory conveniently?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I googled to no avail and could not find any example.

For example, if I want to move files to the current dir I can use `.`
But what if I am in `~/foo` and cd into `~/foo/bar/xyz/dir` and want to move, say, `file.txt` to `~/foo`?

I would think that `mv file.txt -` would be possible. Of course I understand that one thing is to *bring files* from another directory into `.` and another is moving it from where I am to where *I was*.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as _bash_ **and** _zsh_?

Comment: @user1934428 Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @nohillside: Say that the question gets two answers, one for _bash_  and one for _zsh_. Which should then be the accepted answer?

Comment: @user1934428 That's up to the OP, and wouldn't reduce the value of the other answers. I'm aware that other SE sites (especially U&L) have a different view on this, but for rather generic questions the distinction usually is not necessary on AD.

Comment: @nohillside: It's not about reducing value. It is for clarity. If the question asks for the implementation of a certain feature, and there are tags in several languages, does it mean that the OP is wants to get an answer for any one of those languages, or does he want answers for all languages? One principle is that one question in SO should focus on one problem, so if I am interested in the implementation of  a prolem in, say,  C-Shell **and** in fish (for instance), it's clearer to ask two questions, one for each language.

Comment: @user1934428 The OP just used the `command-line` tag, I've added bash and zsh because the vast majority of macOS users use either the previous or the current default shell. And within the scope of the question, both shells are similar enough to have identical answers. But I agree: asking the same for csh or fish might be worth a separate question (or changing the current one into a community wiki asking for the solution in all shells imaginable).

Comment: @nohillside: I get the point. But from the text of the question, you can't conclude whether the OP maybe uses ksh or - even worse - tcsh (which, surprisingly, still is used by many as interactive shell). While the accepted answer would work with ksh, it wouldn't with tcsh. I think in such a case it is better to ask back for clarification, before blindly adding tags.

Comment: @user1934428 If this would be U&L I would agree. Reality on AD is that most users don't know (nor care) which shell they are running (so bash/zsh is usually correct), and those who use a non-standard one tend to ask specific questions (or use U&L anyway for such things because they get better/faster answers there for shells which hardly any macOS user actually uses).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"~-" refers to the previous directory. From the bash man page:

*If  the tilde- prefix  is  a  `~-',  the value of the shell variable OLDPWD, if it is set, is substituted.*

```
$ pwd
/home/me
$ cd /usr
$ pwd
/usr
$ cd
$ pwd
/home/me
$ echo ~-
/usr
```

So

```
mv file.txt ~-
```

will do what you want. Looks like it works in zsh too.

Comment: Wow, using bash for ages but never stumbled over that. Awesome!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! It also works in zsh. You may want to include that in your answer, since the question is also tagged `zsh`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works in zsh. I updated the answer.

Comment: Beautiful and very elegant answer. Thank you!

Comment: I went and found the [relevant zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion). It turns out, zsh even supports full history! `~-` and `~-1` are equivalent and mean previous directory. The one before that is `~-2`, and the one before that `~-3`. That makes `cd ~-5` equivalent to `cd -5`. Really neat!

Answer (score 11):

From `man bash`:

```
OLDPWD The previous working directory as set by the cd command.
```

So, `cp file.txt $OLDPWD` should help here (or `cp file.txt "$OLDPWD"` if you not sure whether the previous path contains whitespace characters).

If you use it often, a shell function might make it easier to use:

```bash
cpprev() {
    cp "$@" "${OLDPWD:?No old directory}/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you as always! Will definitely use this in scripts as well!

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick you could try, using the `cd` command and the fact that `cd -` changes to where you were last:

```
$ pwd
/home/me
$ cd somesubdir
$ pwd
/home/me/somesubdir
$ cd -
/home/me
$ cd -
/home/me/somesubdir
$ cd -
/home/me
$ pwd
/home/me
$ echo $(cd -)
/home/me/somesubdir
$ pwd
/home/me
```

So, you can do something like

```
$ mv file.* $(cd -)/
```

to move files from where you are now to where you were before; this certainly work in bash.